# Преобразование вложенного UL в SELECT(-ы)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой список:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Телефоны</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Apple</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">iPhone 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="">iPhone 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Samsung</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Samsung A3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Samsung A5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Sony</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Sony Xperia XA1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sony Xperia XA2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sony Xperia XA3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Планшеты</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Apple</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">iPad</a></li>
          <li><a href="">iPad 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Samsung</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Samsung Tab 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Samsung Tab 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Samsung Tab 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">LG</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">LG v490</a></li>
          <li><a href="">LG v500</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Как этот список преобразовать в 3 пошаговых select(-а)? Т.е. сначала выбираем "Тип устройства", потом для этого типа устройства выбираем производителя, потом для этого производителя выбираем модель. Получается 3 select(-a):

1. Тип устройства
2. Производитель
3. Модель

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После выбора последнего select нас должно перекидывать на выбранную страницу. Как это можно сделать с помощью JQuery или JS? Может кто-то решал уже такие задачи? Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

это можно делать с ajax
надо подключить jquery v index.php

original link [Dynamic Dependent Select Box using jQuery, Ajax and PHP LisenMe](http://www.lisenme.com/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-php/)

демо здесь [demo](http://www.lisenme.com/demo/dynamic/index.php)

**index.php ↓**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#country').on('change',function(){
        var countryID = $(this).val();
        if(countryID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'country_id='+countryID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#state').html(html);
                    $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#state').html('<option value="">Select country first</option>');
            $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
        }
    });

    $('#state').on('change',function(){
        var stateID = $(this).val();
        if(stateID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'state_id='+stateID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#city').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
        }
    });
});
</script>


  <?php
    //Include database configuration file
    include('dbConfig.php');

    //Get all country data
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM countries WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY country_name ASC");

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
    ?>
    <select name="country" id="country" >
        <option value="">Select Country</option>
        <?php
        if($rowCount > 0){
            while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
                echo '<option value="'.$row['country_id'].'">'.$row['country_name'].'</option>';
            }
        }else{
            echo '<option value="">Country not available</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>

    <select name="state" id="state">
        <option value="">Select country first</option>
    </select>

    <select name="city" id="city">
        <option value="">Select state first</option>
    </select>
```

**ajaxData.php ↓**

```
<?php
//Include database configuration file
include('dbConfig.php');

if(isset($_POST["country_id"]) && !empty($_POST["country_id"])){
    //Get all state data
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM states WHERE country_id = ".$_POST['country_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY state_name ASC");

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    //Display states list
    if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select state</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['state_id'].'">'.$row['state_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">State not available</option>';
    }
}

if(isset($_POST["state_id"]) && !empty($_POST["state_id"])){
    //Get all city data
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cities WHERE state_id = ".$_POST['state_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY city_name ASC");

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    //Display cities list
    if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select city</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['city_id'].'">'.$row['city_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">City not available</option>';
    }
}
?>
```

**dbConfig.php ↓**

```
<?php
//db details
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'lisenme';

//Connect and select the database
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
}
?>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Но в моем случае это не подходит. Надо преобразовать уже этот, существующий список без дополнительного обращения в БД.